# Can't set an user mailbox to a shared mailbox (Exchange)

Tags: powershell, server, exchange-server

I want to set an user mailbox to a shared mailbox with the command below:

```
Set-Mailbox user@domain.com -Type shared
```

I'm getting this error message back (Sorry for bad format):

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object 'user@domain.com' couldn't be found on
'server-vm-02.domain.com'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=SERVER-VM-37,RequestId=1f445bc7-6d4c-4443-a0b3-8a0617d8e83a,TimeStamp=22.05.201
    12:11:51] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] 96F1E1EA,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Recip
  ientTasks.SetMailbox
    + PSComputerName        : server-vm-37.domain.com
```

I've tried it when the user is enabled and disabled in AD.
In the Portal Admin Center the Account is blocked, but in my oppinion it doesn't matter.
And yes I typed the address correctly, I typed instead of the address the name as well as the username, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing a `Set-Mailbox` try a `Get-Mailbox`. Are you sure there is a mailbox under this UPN ? Are you on the Exchange Server or on your computer when you run this cmdlet ?

Comment: When I'm trying the Get-Command I didn't get anything back, so without an error, but without some information, too. I found the "Convert" Button in the Exchange Online Admin Center, so it seems like it was just moved.